# java.security.Principal - creation in HttpServletRequest and Spring Security

Tags: java, model-view-controller, authentication, spring-security, authorization

1. I am unable to find how the java.security.Principal in HttpServletRequest is created - who is responsible? How it is done? Is it necessarily kept in Session?
2. How it is connected to Spring Security?
3. Are there any alternatives to Spring Security which uses Principal for User authorization/authentication?
4. How would one implement own user authorization/authentication so that Principal would contain the current user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. typically, Principal object putting in the session after successful login.See [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1833).
2. Springs `Authentication` interface extends `Principal` interface
3. Alternatively you can use [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)
4. Implement own `UserDetailsService` which wil return your User object(it must implement UserDetails interface) See [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-userdetailsservice).

Answer (score -1):

The Principal will be set by Spring Security based upon your Spring Security configuration.

To implement this, please see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html

Comment: Obviously I've already seen this documentation, but my question is rather in general, not depending on Spring Security.